# Editor won't accept else in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Can anyone explain why I am getting a syntax error on the below, my editor won't accept the "else":

```
    for i in self.jobs:
        with open('postcodes.csv', 'rb') as f: #see http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples
                reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] == self.jobs[i][3]:
                    self.jobs[i].append((row[1],row[2]))
                else:
                    self.jobs[i].append("Latitude & Longitude not available")
```

Comment: You have bad indention in the line `reader = csv.reader(f)`

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces in your code. Don't do this. Ideally, you should configure your editor to only use spaces for indentation.

Comment: Run your code with `python -tt <scriptname.py>` to detect any specific problems with indentation.

Comment: "fix my syntax error" questions are a little off topic.

Comment: @PaulBentham This site has guidelines for what it considers a good question. A good question for this site should be relevant to other programmers. "Fix my typo" questions are not relevant to other programmers.

Comment: you should try out emacs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a coding error (bad indentation) that will not help others in the future

Comment: @joaquin On the contrary, I think it helps people understand that indentation is important!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is inconsistent because it's a mixture of space and tab characters, as you can see in the screenshot below where I've turned on a "visible whitespace" mode in my editor.

I suggest you convert all the tabs in your code to space characters -- perhaps your editor has a command to do that -- and avoid mixing the two in the future. Since, as you're discovering the hard way, it can cause bizarre and hard-to-diagnosis errors.

[image: screenshot of code in my editor with whitespace character visible]

Answer (score 0):

In the future, consider evaluating your code for PEP-8 deviations:

http://pych.atomidata.com/